# Styled-component not injecting all the different css for handling different props

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, styled-components

I would like to know what can potentially cause styled-components to not inject all the neccessary css into a page's header.

I have declared a super simple button in an existing project like so:

```
const Button = styled.button`
    background-color: ${props => props.disabled ? "red" : "blue"}
`
```

And used it like so:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.changeValue} />
            <Button disabled={this.state.value === "123"}>Button</Button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The problem is the button will display as expected on load (eg. red) but it doesn't have the blue style when the state changes.

[image]

[image]

Looking at the generated html, this is caused by the 'blue' style (.hqrbog) not injected into the header

```
<style type="text/css" data-styled-components="jiLefI" data-styled-components-is-local="true">
     /* sc-component-id: sc-bdVaJa */
     .sc-bdVaJa {}
     .jiLefI{background-color:red;}
</style>

<div data-reactroot="">
    <input value="12" class="drop-val">
    <button class="sc-bdVaJa hqrbog">Button</button>
</div>
```

When I put these code in a new app created with create-react-component, everything works. But they just dont work in this existing project.

I'm wondering what can cause styled-component to not inject css insto the header properly? I'm suspecting its something to do with how the webpack or babel is set up but I don't know where to start.

Comment: once try debugging styled-components with babel plugin - babel-plugin-styled-components. Might help you

Comment: Can you share the implementation of `changeValue` method ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your attribute from `disabled` to something else.

Comment: Hello, that didn't make a difference. Besides, the code works fine as is in a new create-react-app project. So the code is correct, it must be something to do with how the project I'm trying to use it in is set up, but I don't know where to look